# Mosfet & saturation

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Hi, I am a little bit confused about part b. If someone could please correct me, during my lesson, I learned that saturation means that the absolute value of Vds must be greater than the absolute value of (Vgs-Vt). From the circuit, I see that |-7.6| is greater than |-5-(-1.5)|. So I can assume saturation. However, when I try the formula, I get (0.5)(80)(-5-(-1.5))^2*(1+|0.02|)=480.2, which is supposedly incorrect.

Comment: What's the answer given?

Answer (score 1):

In your formula for Ids in saturation region, (1+ |0.02 * Vds|) is the multiplication factor, when channel length modulation is considered. You forgot to multiply Vds with lambda.